# Opening a new window popup from a HyperLinkField of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I'm using **GridView** and need a new window popup from **HyperLink** field with no toolbars, and not resizable.

I pass the value of **ID** (in querystring) to the new page.

How to do that?

I'm using **Master Page**.

Example code is like:

```
    NavigateUrl='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Attachment").ToString()) ? 
                    String.Format("sDetailsUpload.aspx?sID={0}", 
                   _2Version_Mprep.Base64ForUrlEncode(Eval("ID").ToString())) :
                    Eval("Attachment").ToString())%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your **Markup** webpage.

I hope I was helpful.

```
NavigateUrl='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Attachment").ToString()) ? 
                  String.Format("sDetailsUpload.aspx?sID={0}", 
                  _2Version_Mprep.Base64ForUrlEncode(Eval("ID").ToString()) : 
                  Eval("Attachment").ToString())%>'
                  onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'sID',
                 'left=20,top=20,width=750,height=450,toolbar=0,resizable=0');
                  return false;"
```